# can unit tests & espresso tests coexist in the same package

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to set up a few Espresso tests for my app.

I want to call *onActivityResult()* from one of the tests, but since that is protected, it won't work if the test is in a different package.

But if that test is in the same package, then trying to run unit tests fails with an error like:

Class not found: "com.example.MainActivityTest"Empty test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not invoke `onActivityResult()` from your test. What you should do, as the test would involve more than one Activity is to use [UiAutomator](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator) to invoke the other Activity that send the result, interact with it to actually send the result and then in your Activity under test verify that whatever is reflected in the UI when the result is received happened.

Comment: even better approach would be to use Espresso Intents where you could basically intercept "request" intent and respond with canned response. If this scenario is possible of course from test perspective :)

Comment: Espresso-Intents is an extension to Espresso, which enables validation and stubbing of Intents *sent out* by the application under test. Then, you will be able to test the `startActivityForResult()` part but not if the expected behavior is showed when an Intent is received in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: OK, I figured out a way to use Espresso Intents to call *onActivityResult*.  Basically like the *Stubbing Intents* section from https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/ but replace *toPackage* in the stub with *hasComponent* to match the activity that would send the result.  So changing that dialog to an activity was a little more disruptive to my tests than I'd hoped, but that does fix it with the espresso tests insulated from the normal unit tests.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano That's not really true. Take a look at 'intending' part of Espresso intents. You can intercept intent sent out by application and make Espresso auto-respond with canned response. After you return canned response, onActivityResult will be called in your app, so you can test if your app has processed this response correctly.